# Does "where" loads data before setup method executes?

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I want to construct where conditions based on setup data. But seems like where executes before setup method so I'm getting `null` object. I'm I right and how can I construct `where` data based on my `setup` data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't. The `where` block *must* run before the `setup` block/method for reasons discussed on the mailing list (http://forum.spockframework.org). However, a `where` block may refer to `@Shared` variables, which can be initialized directly or in `setupSpec()`. If necessary, you can write multiple spec classes with different `setupSpec()` methods and keep them all in the same file.

Often, an alternative is to turn things around and use simple values (e.g. strings and numbers) in the `where` block, from which more complex objects are constructed in the `setup` block.